# apollo angular fragment ambigous

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I have a working graphql query that fetches a bunch of objects from my backend. I am trying to factor out a fragment from the query, so that I can use it in a mutation as well. However, I keep getting an 'Error: Ambiguous GraphQL document: contains 2 operations' error when I do that. Would appreciate some input on what I am doing wrong.

```
    const TICKET_FRAGMENT = gql`{
      fragment ticketfragment on TicketNode {
        id
        title
        description
        ticketId
        created
        // Some other fields
      }
    }`;

    const PERSON_TICKETS = gql`
      query allTickets ($person_id: ID!) {
        allTickets (id: $person_id) {
          edges {
            node {
              ...ticketfragment
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ${TICKET_FRAGMENT}
    `;

  getTickets(personID: string): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<any>> {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
      query: PERSON_TICKETS,
      variables: {
        person_id: personID
      }
    }).valueChanges;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
const TICKET_FRAGMENT = gql`
      fragment ticketfragment on TicketNode {
        id
        title
        description
        ticketId
        created
        // Some other fields
      }
   `;
```